# Kerberos kinit: Preauthentication failed while getting initial credentials

Tags: python, kerberos

I am trying to set up a login verification system using Kerberos in a Docker container. I want to have a python script run shell commands to create a keytab file containing the user info and then use kinit to create a ticket. Sample code below:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['ktutil'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
commands = f"""
addent -password -p {name}@{realm} -k 1 -e aes256-cts -s "{realm}{name}"
{password}
wkt {path}/{name}.keytab
quit
"""
stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input=commands)
print("stdout:", stdout)
print("stderr:", stderr)
process.wait()
args = ['kinit', '-k', '-t', f'{path}/{name}.keytab', f'{name}@{realm}']
process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
print("stdout:", stdout)
print("stderr:", stderr)
process.wait()
```

The keytab file seems to be created fine when I execute the script, however, when I try to run the second subprocess I get an error stating that `kinit: Preauthentication failed while getting initial credentials`. I tried to create the keytab in the command line and create a ticket using kinit locally, and that worked fine. It however seems like the same does not get achieved when the keytab file is created inside a docker container. This makes me suspect the file maybe does not have the right access.

I have tried to search for answers before, one of which suggested to add `-s "{realm}{name}" so the first line after ktutil, but to no avail.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why are you trying to dynamically create a keytab like this?  Does the user's principal already exist (and if not, why not)?  The first command in this sequence looks scarily susceptible to injection attacks; if the user gets to pick `name` or `password`, can they make arbitrary changes to the Kerberos environment?

Comment: This is my first time using Kerberos, so I might go about it completely wrong; but I basically am following the steps here to create a keytab: https://kb.iu.edu/d/aumh

The user's principal does already exist, I want to verify their credentials so that I can use the smbprotocol to access a network drive; that can be done using a Kerberos ticket.

Again, I can be completely wrong and would like to hear so.

As for your last question, they login using name/password, but only verified credentials will pass to the backend. Later I want to work with ticket data instead

Comment: Is this AD? Are you sure you're creating the key using the correct salt? Have you tried using `-f` to let the system retrieve the correct salt directly? (If it's the system that does kinit, surely it has access to the KDC...) I'm assuming it's AD, and AD doesn't guarantee that the salt will be in the standard format.